# Making a Site More "Up-to-Date" - Ideas?

Tags: web-development, marketing

We have a website and want it to be more up-to-date. So far, we've made the site compatible with mobile devices and created a FaceBook page for it. What are some other things we can do for our site to make it more up-to-date?

Comment: sounds like you may want to do a bit of reading on social media.  Without knowing what your site is for, this is a difficult question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is your target audience?

If it is a younger audience then tying in with the latest "yoof" trends could work. Or what about a twitter feed? There are quite a few nice JQuery feeds that integrate nicely into a site giving it a nice fresh feel.

Up to date and current content always works. Nothing makes a site look staler than out of date old content.

How about running some competitions, user polls (interaction) etc.

Again as lainie says, without knowing any details about your site it is very hard to help...

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to make specific suggestions without more detail. That said, there are some general ideas you may wish to explore...

- add a blog, if there isn't one already - adds some amount of freshness and provides the possibility of two-way interaction between yourself and your audience
- you mention having created a Facebook page - maybe look at getting a Twitter account as well, to provide an additional communication channel
- investigate social media options - you don't need to use every service out there, but sign up for social media/networking sites that have some relevance to your site. As an example, if your site were about photography, it could make sense to have accounts on Flickr or Smugmug as well.

Answer (score 0):

add some glossy buttons...

*SCNR*